# CRUD operations using Ember-Model

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js, ember-model

Here,I am trying to implement CRUD operations using [ember-model](https://github.com/ebryn/ember-model).
I am totally new to ember environment,actually i don't have much understanding of [ember-model](https://github.com/ebryn/ember-model).

Here,i am trying to add new product and delete existing one.I am using inner node of `fixture`
i.e. `cart_items`.My this fixture contains two node i.e. `logged_in` and `cart_items` and this what my fixture structure :

```
Astcart.Application.adapter = Ember.FixtureAdapter.create();

Astcart.Application.FIXTURES = [
{
    "logged_in": {
        "logged": true,
        "username": "sachin",
        "account_id": "4214"
    },
    "cart_items": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Samsung Galaxy Tab 2",
        "qty": "1",
        "price": "100",
        "subtotal": "100"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Samsung Galaxy Tab 2",
        "qty": "1",
        "price": "100",
        "subtotal": "100"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Samsung Galaxy Tab 2",
        "qty": "1",
        "price": "100",
        "subtotal": "100"
    }
    ]           
}
];
```

I want to this fixture struture only to get data in one service call from server.
Now,here is my code which i am using to add and delete product from `cart_items`

```
Astcart.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return Astcart.Application.find();
    }
}); 

Astcart.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
 save: function(){                    
    this.get('model').map(function(application) {                
        var new_cart_item = application.get('cart_items').create({name: this.get('newProductDesc'),qty: this.get('newProductQty'),price: this.get('newProductPrice'),subtotal: this.get('newProductSubtotal')});                
        new_cart_item.save();
            });
 },    
 deleteproduct: function(product){
    if (window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?")) {                           
    this.get('model').map(function(application) {
        application.get('cart_items').deleteRecord(product);                    
    });            
  }
}
});
```

But when i am trying to save product i am getting an exception

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'get'
```

And when i am trying to delete product i am getting an exception

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'deleteRecord'
```

Here,i also want to implement one functionality i.e. on every save i need to check if that product is already present or not.
If product is not present then only save new product other wise update existing product.
But i don't have any idea how to do this?

[I have posted my complete code here.](http://jsfiddle.net/sachin1989/6WPrR/)
Can anyone help me to make this jsfiddle work?

### Update

[I have updated my code here with debugs.](http://jsfiddle.net/sachin1989/WZ2Sq/)

Here, i am not getting any exception but record is also not getting delete.
I am not getting what is happening here?

Can anyone help me to make this jsfiddle work?

Answer (score 0):

'this' context changes within your save method. You need to use the 'this' of the controller and not the map functions. Try this:

```
save: function(){
    var self = this;
    self.get('model').map(function(application) {                
        var new_cart_item = application.get('cart_items').create({
                               name: self.get('newProductDesc'),
                               qty: self.get('newProductQty'),
                               price: self.get('newProductPrice'),
                               subtotal: self.get('newProductSubtotal')
                               });                
        new_cart_item.save();
   });
 }
```

Comment: No,still there is an issue with context. I am getting an error : "Uncaught Error: Ember.Adapter must implement createRecord"

Comment: Your structure is little wierd. I want to try something like this. `Astcart.Application.find(<id>).get('cart_items').get(product.get('id')).deleteRecord()`. But you applciation just stands barebone. Can you try starting with simple models first and then slowly move to complicated model? Also why Ember RC7?

Comment: My basic requirement is i want multiple nodes and  array in fixture.So that i can get data in one call from server.
If there is any issue with my model structure then please explain me "How to  build such model structure?"
I am new to emberjs and i will upgrade my emberjs files.
It will be more helpful if you explain this issue with my jsfiddle.